# Would a message box appear when a macro is called from a server?

Tags: ms-access, vba

This may seem like a question that would just require me to try it out and see but I can't do that.

I've been working on an application for my company that can generate what is called an Exceptions report based on whether or not certain fields are blank.
This can be run manually or be called from a server - it's called by the server on the first of each month.

The question - because both runs call the same macro they'll both run the same function. So if I place a `MsgBox` function inside the macro would that block the report from generating, when run from the server?

[I know I could in essence duplicate the function and create two macros, one for the server and one for the user - but don't want to do that]

Its purpose when called manually would be just to inform the user if it ran successfully (Found exceptions or didn't find any) I didn't want to add it just in case it does block the rest of the code from executing.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly if the code will sometimes run unattended then you don't want to throw up a `MsgBox` if there's nobody around to see it. If you know the Windows Networking name of the server then you might consider experimenting with having your code do something like

```
Dim wshNet As Object
Set wshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
If wshNet.ComputerName <> "MYSERVERNAME" Then
    MsgBox "Exceptions found (or not)."
End If
Set wshNet = Nothing
```

Comment: I was thinking it needed something to detect the server name or perhaps the calling command? This is good I'm going to see if I can get this into the next version of the application. Thanks